# Sencha Cmd broken: Why does 'app build' ignore any command line parameters?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I've upgraded Sencha cmd to v4 and I used to be able to build to a specific archive path and destination path. This was crucial as the build server removes the source code folder and archive path for each build. I had the paths output on the IIS server away from the build server, so that they are never lost.

However, my build process is failing now as the path parameters supplied to the sencha cmd don't do anything.

If I type:

```
Sencha help app build
```

I get the following help:

```
Syntax

sencha app build [options] [environment] \
                           [destination] \
                           [archive]
```

But supplying these parameters has no effect to the location of the output.

Can anyone point me to the documentation which shows if this has changed and how I rectify it. I can't find anything on the their site which shows how to build for production and have it output to separate paths. Also I'd like to know why the Sencha Tools change so much. This wreaks havoc on any existing build systems because things suddenly stop working.

See below:

```
C:\Development\Projects\IEApp>sencha app build --archive C:\temp\build\IEApp\bui
ldarchive --destination C:\temp\build\IEApp\Destination --environment production
```

Everything builds ok, but the **C:\temp\build** folder is empty.

Comment: no-one had this problem?

Comment: This is definitely a bug. I've tried with Sencha Cmd v3 with the same command line params and it works fine. Can anyone point me in the right direction to raise this on their site? It seems I can't raise a bug even though I'm a member of their forum.

Comment: Update: Still broken as of Version 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you where the doc is, but to get CMD to build to a different directory, this is what I do:

modify the file: .sencha\app\production.properties as follows:

```
# =============================================================================
# This file provides an override point for default variables defined in 
# production.defaults.properties. These properties are only imported when building
# for the "production" environment.
#
# Properties defined in this file take priority over build.properties but are
# only loaded for "production" builds.
# =============================================================================
build.dir=${app.dir}/../../ExtJSApps/dashboard
```

Comment: Watch out! It's broken in cmd 5.0.1. Make sure to upgrade or comment out `"output"` property in `app/app.defaults.json`.