# How do I build a sencha app to target production in a specific folder?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

Using the latest Sencha Cmd tool v4.0.2, how do I build an app for production mode into a **specific** folder not into its default build folder within the app folder.

I am trying to do this from the command line but not succeeding at all.
Tried this according to their help on command line but had no success with it for several weeks now:

[Sencha Cmd broken: Why does 'app build' ignore any command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956287/sencha-cmd-broken-why-does-app-build-ignore-any-command-line-parameters)

No-one seems to know what the issue is. Am I the only person in the world who is actually encountering an issue with this!?  Any help appreciated from anyone with some knowledge of the Sencha products greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to this as the last post in the thread:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?247180-Sencha-Cmd-v3.0.0.190-does-not-use-app.json-buildpath-settings/page2

I added the following to the sencha.cfg within the .sencha\workspace folder.

```
workspace.build.dir=C:/builds/TolMobile
```

Not sure why packager.json contains an output path with the following:

```
"outputPath":"../build/",
```

It doesn't seem to even be used. If its redundant why don't they just remove it? In addition I still haven't got their command line arguments to work either. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

change "outputPath" in packager.json file.

```
/**
     * @cfg  outputPath
     * @required
     * This is where the built application file with be saved. Make sure that output path is not in your input path, you may get into endless recursive copying
     */
    "outputPath":"../build/",
```

then build with no cmd parameters .. >sencha app build production

Comment: Can you help me with a sencha touch and phonegap problem I posted [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457136/sencha-touch-with-phonegap-using-sencha-cmd-and-phonegap-build-causes-error) . would really appreciate it.

Comment: This didn't actually do anything. The app still built into the build folder underneath the app folder even though I had changed it.

Comment: try to change build.dir in .sencha/defaults.properties 

`build.dir=${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}`

Answer (score 0):

To built the builds folder relative to your project.
Add to the .sencha/app/sencha.cfg
workspace.build.dir=builds/