# Sencha cmd separate folder in build

Tags: extjs

I need to separate an folder in my application in another app.js build
generated by sencha cmd, this folder is being used by another applications and i need to have in web cache.

I read the documentation and I dont found nothing related to this

Exists another way to do this, without having to create a unique application for the specific folder ?

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440574/how-do-i-build-a-sencha-app-to-target-production-in-a-specific-folder

Comment: Thanks man, i've been reading about packages in sencha cmd and i solve my problem understanding about it